# PHP - CURL Connection to a Website that uses Office365 to login

Tags: php, curl, single-sign-on, office365

I need help to login with PHP-CURL on a website that uses Office365 SSO (Single Sign-On)

In the past, I had no problem to use curl in PHP to login using an username and a password like this :

```
<?php
$URL = "https://intra.epitech.eu/"


// if (!isset($argv[1]))
  // die("Please specify the event URL");

$url_event = rtrim("https://intra.epitech.eu/module/2016/B-PAV-450/PAR-5-1/registered", "/");

$ch = curl_init();
$opts_base = array( CURLOPT_URL => $URL.'login',
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=> FALSE,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.txt",
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.txt",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Connection: Keep-Alive')
                    );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts_base);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"login":"firstname.name@epitech.eu","password":"PASSWORD123"}');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_event);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($html);
// Some code...
?>
```

But a recent Udate removed the account login system was removing and now it uses the Office365 SSO authentification "Connect With Office" : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=e05d4149-1624-4627-a5ba-7472a39e43ab&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fintra.epitech.eu%2Fauth%2Foffice365&state=%2F

So my question is : How can I connect to the website using CURL to make so request on it ?

I have to create a website that uses the Office SSO connection to login and then use the user's informations to login to my School intranet using that SSO Auth et get some informations like the user's grade "Admin, student, etc.) and make some cURL POST request to push some data.

I have absolutely NO IDEA on how to connect to the intranet using Office authentification :/

if the auth is correctly done, I should have some json data like these :

```js
[
    {
        "login": "user2.lastname@epitech.eu",
        "picture": "https:\/\/cdn.local.epitech.eu\/userprofil\/blabla.jpg",
        "title": "Firstname Lastname",
        "location": "FR\/PAR",
        "promo": 2019,
        "course_code": "bachelor\/classic",
        "grade": "-",
        "cycle": "bachelor",
        "date_ins": "2016-09-13 21:49:05",
        "credits": 6,
        "flags": [],
        "semester": "B5"
    },
    {
        "login": "otherguy.lastname",
        "picture": "https:\/\/cdn.local.epitech.eu\/userprofil\/blabla.bmp",
        "title": "Firstname LastName",
        "location": "FR\/PAR",
        "promo": 2019,
        "course_code": "bachelor\/classic",
        "grade": "-",
        "cycle": "bachelor",
        "date_ins": "2016-09-14 01:39:36",
        "credits": 6,
        "flags": [],
        "semester": "B5"
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
```

But I cannot login... so it's hard to continue with my project...

I really hope you will be able to help me with that.
And please feel free to ask any information you want if you need to since english is not my native language.

thanks in advance,
best regards.
Yannick.

Comment: 1) Are you receiving any error in the error console? 2) Why you are using `curl_exec` two times? Is it some mandatory step for Office SSO?

Comment: I execute the script via CLI on a linux Shell using "php <script.php>" I don't get any error but I cannot login so the var_dump($html) returns me the content of the login page and not the page I need to get (the one with the JSON informations beceause I need a valid access to get it, so if I can't successfully login, I cannot continue. About the double curl_exec() Is is just that I login before doing my request, I may not be the best way I don't now but it was working with the previous systeme that was simple credentials and not Office365 SSO, regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience in use the Office SSO process, but (based on your comments) maybe your problem is in the use of the same cURL handle to deal with two different requests. Below is some suggestions.

Try to create one handle for each request.

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL , $URL.'login');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , "cookie.txt"); it will save your cookies in the cookie.txt file after curl_close()
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Connection: Keep-Alive'));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"login":"firstname.name@epitech.eu","password":"PASSWORD123"}');
$html = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
```

See that I prefer curl_setopt against curl_setopt_array, but it's just a personal preference and shouldn't affect your script.

Unless you already have the file `cookie.txt`, the line `curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE , "cookie.txt");` is not necessary. This file will be created after the curl_close since you are using the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. See the refence for these options in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php).

> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR: The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

Also, this is the perfect step to debug your code. Try to print out the `$html` and see its contents, maybe it will give will some tip. You can also use the option `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `TRUE` and analyze your request with more precision.

After ensure that the answer is correct, create a second handle to the second request.

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url_event);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE , "cookie.txt");
$html2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

var_dump($html2);
```

I think that here is the right place for `curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE , "cookie.txt");`, since now the file exists. The documentation again:

> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE:   The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.